# How can I summate radio and checkbox responses that are variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sum, field

Here is what the site with the fields looks like overall:

http://cs1.calstatela.edu:8280/~cs120s06/labs/orderpizza.html

Here is a code snippet:

```
<p>size</p>
<input type="radio" name="size1" value="10" id="size1">large<br>
<input type="radio" name="size2" value="8" id="size2">medium<br>
<input type="radio" name="size2" value="5" id="size2">small
```

How can I have a submit button at the end that will greet the user with their name and then add up the costs, in this case the cost would be 10 dollars for just a large pizza with no toppings. But you can see the source code in the HTML I linked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript. I have used jquery along with the javascript code below. It will change the text of the submit button whenever the user interacts with your form. I have created this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGeEYB for you to play around. Good luck :)

```
$('form').on("click mousedown mouseup focus blur keydown change",function(e) {
         var firstName = $('[name="firstName"]').val();
         var lastName = $('[name="lastName"]').val();
         var price = 0;
         $(':checked').each(function() {
             var addprice = $(this).val();
             price += parseInt(addprice);
         });

         $("[type='submit']").val('Hello '+firstName+' '+lastName+'. You have to pay $'+price+'. Is this okay?');
    });
```